# Is there a way to compile C++ code to Microsoft .Net CIL (bytecode)?

Tags: .net, c++, browser, cil

I.e., a web browser client would be written in C++ !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a two choices. Managed C++ (/clr:oldSyntax, no longer maintained) or C++/CLI (definitely maintained). You'll want to use /clr:safe for in-browser software, because you wnat the browser to be able to verify it.

Answer (score 4):

This was originally known as [Managed C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B), but as Josh commented, it has been superceded by [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).

Comment: Managed C++ is no longer maintained, try C++/CLI

Answer (score 1):

Use the /clr compile option

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Visual Studio can compile "managed" C++.  I'm not sure I understand your "web browser client" reference though; do you mean you want to compile your C++ to something that will run with Silverlight?

Comment: yeah basically i want to split an existing desktop app written in C++ into a client and server, where the client can run on desktop OR browser! thanks!

Comment: Its not possible to run the same binary on both desktop and silverlight - although the APIs are in large part compatible, the dependent libraries themselves are different.  So you can have the same source code, but not the same binaries.